# How to do ReplayGain for music videos?

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player, music, media-player

I have a playlist of several music videos, but the videos have different loudness.

I want to play the playlist so that the loudness of each video would be the same, without the need to manually readjust the volume control for each video.

I do not want to modify the original video files to avoid any quality loss.

I know that VLC and WinAmp media players have a ReplayGain option that can read loudness information from file tags and readjust accordingly playback volume for each audio file, but it does not seem to work for video files.

**Is it possible to accomplish such "per video file" volume normalization "on the fly" during playback of a playlist without modifying the original video files?**

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your answer is in your question.

**VLC: Preferences, Audio, tick option "Normalize volume to:".**

And you get "per video file volume normalization on the fly during playback".

It is dynamic normalization. So it calculates loudness of chunk, something like 10 seconds. And amplify it to marked in option value.

Every decent videoplayer has this option. It is useful for too quiet audiotracks in movies. Or if audiotrack loudness floats too much.

But as you understand dynamic normalization means loudness going to be floaty around marked level.

Comment: Hi, Anton. My VLC player (v. 2.2.2) has no "Normalize volume to:" option. Which version of VLC do you use?

Comment: @GreenBear Tools > Preferences > Audio should have the "Normalise volume to..." option. It is there in 2.2.1 and in the latest version 2.2.4. I can't imagine it is not there in 2.2.2.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, guys, found it. I had "All settings" option on, and it was not there. Then I switched to "Simple settings", and found it. I also found there is a "Volume normalizer" filter. I suppose it does the same. Do you know if there is any documentation on these settings? I checked the Videolan web site, but found no description of them.

Comment: This is not replaygain'ing. Normalizing only adjusts volume to the maximum value of audio, not the average and between files. Poor understanding of concept.